Death in service benefit
A close family member recently passed away by natural causes whilst at work. An employment he has held for many many years at a large local company. We have since been in contact with his employer to request death in service benefit. Told in no uncertain terms that it’s not a benefit they offer as a company.
Since this conversation we have now been unofficially informed by another company member that it is indeed a benefit that is offered but reluctant to offer due to increases of insurance premiums.
At present, we can’t find a copy of his contract with the company and we assume that if we request one it will be ‘lost’ or not transferred as it was more than likely a paper, hand written copy many years ago.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how we best approach this? Understandably each individual position at the firm will be working for different benefits/ salary’s but this is something that would really help his wife.
Uk location.

Question: Your Unofficial company source - can they show a copy of either their contract or some internal documentation that states it is a benefit?

If the company says it isn't there, it probably isn't. This may have been an optional insurance program the company let people buy into at a discount, rather than a benefit. Or your source
may be confusing it with another employer. Check your source; check your contract, check your files paperwork . My employer gave me a "free" $1000 policy as part of a marketing agreement where the insurer got to try to sell us more coverage; I didn't buy, so that $1k is all there is... if even that is still active.

I’m hoping to see a copy of another employees contract in the hopes benefits will be listed- my own employment offers a list of benefits however they’re not listed on the contract but in the employees handbook. If we do find the benefit listed on another employees contract I’m hoping it atleast gives us something to question.

Unfortunately, most of us don't work at your company and can't share our contracts. You really do need to track this down within n the company.

First of all: sorry for your loss.
Start by requesting a copy of the contract. At that point, it hopefully all gets resolved.
If they "can't" provide a copy of the contract, you're going to need to talk to a lawyer, but your case against the company will essentially be:

They do offer this benefit to others, as shown by your conversation with the other company member; obviously things get a lot easier if they are prepared to provide a copy of their contract.
They can't prove that your family member didn't have this benefit, because they "lost" the contract.

On balance of probabilities (this is a civil case), I'd say you have a more than reasonable chance of winning. But that's what an actual professional lawyer can guide you on, legal advice on the Internet is worth less than you paid for it.

I think this was my line of thinking- that if they can’t produce a copy of their contract there may be a case of themselves having to prove they don’t offer the benefit- especially if they offer it to other employees
